# How to link or add a default directory for images in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, basic

So I've been working on this simple program to look up specs for drawings. One of the specs is a thumbnail image of the drawing. I didn't want to try managing what could be 1000's of images (that could be changed at anytime) in the database so I created a true/false field instead. If true for that record, then the corresponding thumbnail is displayed in a picture box.

It works beautifully.... if I type the entire path in the code. But what if I give the program to a friend? So I've been trying to find a way that the program would find the images to no avail. I've been searching for answers all day and am finally at this point.... asking for help.

```
   If CBool(db.getField("PDF")) = True Then
        'pbxPDFThumb.ImageLocation = ("C:\Users\Reed Havoc\Desktop\RCM   Database\RCM DataBase 2015 8g\RCM Plans Tool\RCM Plans Tool\Thumbnails\PDFs\" & db.getField("Plan_Num") & "pdf.jpg")
        pbxPDFThumb.ImageLocation = ("\Thumbnails\PDFs\" & db.getField("Plan_Num") & "pdf.jpg")
    End If

The first line is the entire path commented out to try the second, foreshortened path.
```

I've been adding my image thumbnail directory to the project in all the different directories that VS establishes on start-up but none seems to be a default so that my added image directory will be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear so I'll have 2 answers.

If drawing are not going to be added but you only use the ones you already have, simply store all of the pictures in the project's resource file, which is accessible through code and builds into the EXE

If the user adds drawings themselves there are two options. There's the more user friendly method: Save the files in a Local appdata folder for the application.
Or, less user friendly and ultimately more work for you. when the application starts, ask the user to identify a directory that does / will contain images.